# Multiclass classification per class recall equals per class accuracy?

Tags: scikit-learn

I've got a multiclass problem. I'm using `sklearn.metrics` to calculate the confusion matrix, overall accuracy, per class precision, per class recall and per class F1-score.

Now I wanted to calculate the per class accuracy. Since there is no method in sklearn for this I used another one which i got from a google search. I've now realised, that the per class recall equals the per class accuracy. Can anyone explain to me if this holds true and if yes, why?

I found an explanation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-ii-the-f1-score-ebe8b2c2ca1), but I'm not sure since there the micro-recall equals the overall accuracy if I'm understanding it correctly. And I'm looking for the per class accuracy.

Comment: I experienced the same thing across different datasets, would be very interested in a response!

Comment: are you looking for per-class accuracy as a separate metric for each class, or the average per-class accuracy as a single value?

Answer (score 0):

This generally doesn't hold. Accuracy and recall are calculated using different formulas and are different measures explaining something else.

Recall is the percentage of true positive data points compared to all data points that are predicted as positive by your classifier.

Accuracy is the percentage of all examples that are classified correctly, including positive and negative.

If they are equal, this is either coincidence or you have an error is your method of calculating them. Most likely this will be coincidence.

*EDIT:*

I will show why it's not the case with an example that can be generalised to N classes.

Let's assume three classes: 0, 1, 2 with the following confusion matrix:

```
[[3 0 1]
[2 5 0]
[0 1 4]]
```

When we want to calculate measures per class, we do this binary. For example for class 0, we combine 1 and 2 into 'not 0'. This results in the following confusion matrix:

```
[[3 1]
 [2 9]]
```

Resulting in:

- TP = 3
- FT = 5
- FN = 1
- TN = 9

Accuracy = (TN + TP) / (N + P)
Recall = TP / (TN + FN)

So you can already tell from these formulas, that they are really not equal. To disprove an hypothesis in mathematics it suffices to show a counter example. In this case an example that show that accuracy is not equal to recall.

In this example filled in we get:

Accuracy = 12/18 = 2/3
Recall = 3/4

And 2/3 is not equal to 3/4. Thus disproving the hypothesis that per class accuracy is equal to per class recall.

It is however also possible to provide examples for which the hypothesis is correct. But because it is not in general, it is disproven.

Comment: I disagree, I get the same result across multiple datasets with multiple numbers of classes. it's not a coincidence, there seems to be some mathematical equivalence for which an explanation would be great

Comment: I really don't think this is the case, I will update my answer to show why.

Comment: You are calculating overall accuracy and recall right? The question is about per class accuracy and per class recall. The official sklearn docs say: "The balanced accuracy in binary and multiclass classification problems to deal with imbalanced datasets. It is defined as the average of recall obtained on each class."

Comment: No I am not, read this line: "When we want to calculate measures per class, we do this binary. For example for class 0, we combine 1 and 2 into 'not 0'. "

Comment: Yeah, I think you then also need to calculate the same for 'not 1' and take the average of the two per-class value to get the overall recall-macro or balanced accuracy value

Comment: Yes, can be. But what does that have to do with this question? This is about per class accuracy and per class recall.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced same results. because per class Recall = TP/TP+FN , Here TP+FN is same as all the samples of a class. So the formula becomes similar to accuracy.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32587719)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for average per-class accuracy as a single metric or per-class accuracy as separate metrics for each class.

1. For per-class accuracy as a separate metric for each class, see the code below. It's the same as recall-micro per class.
2. For average per-class accuracy as a single metric, it is equivalent to recall-macro (which is equivalent to balanced accuracy in sklearn). See the code blow.

##### Here is the empirical demonstration in code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, balanced_accuracy_score, recall_score

label_class1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
label_class2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
labels = label_class1 + label_class2

pred_class1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pred_class2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
pred = pred_class1 + pred_class2

# 1. calculate accuracy scores per class
score_accuracy_class1 = accuracy_score(label_class1, pred_class1)
score_accuracy_class2 = accuracy_score(label_class2, pred_class2)
print(score_accuracy_class1) # 0.6
print(score_accuracy_class2) # 0.9

# 2. calculate recall scores per class
score_recall_class1 = recall_score(label_class1, pred_class1, average='micro')
score_recall_class2 = recall_score(label_class2, pred_class2, average='micro')
print(score_recall_class1) # 0.6
print(score_recall_class2) # 0.9

assert score_accuracy_class1 == score_recall_class1
assert score_accuracy_class2 == score_recall_class2

# 3. this also means that average per-class accuracy is equivalent to averaged recall and balanced accuracy
score_balanced_accuracy1 = (score_accuracy_class1 + score_accuracy_class2) / 2
score_balanced_accuracy2 = (score_recall_class1 + score_recall_class2) / 2
score_balanced_accuracy3 = balanced_accuracy_score(labels, pred)
score_balanced_accuracy4 = recall_score(labels, pred, average='macro')
print(score_balanced_accuracy1) # 0.75
print(score_balanced_accuracy2) # 0.75
print(score_balanced_accuracy3) # 0.75
print(score_balanced_accuracy4) # 0.75

# balanced accuracy, average per-class accuracy and recall-macro are equivalent
assert score_balanced_accuracy1 == score_balanced_accuracy2 == score_balanced_accuracy3 == score_balanced_accuracy4
```

These official docs say: "balanced accuracy ... is defined as the average of recall obtained on each class."
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with the OP's question about per class accuracy and recall.

Comment: as I'm saying in the response, the sklearn docs literally say that balanced accuracy "is defined as the average of recall obtained on each class". And balanced accuracy is also equivalent to per class averaged accuracy. How does this not respond to the question?

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you want per class accuracy as a separate metric per class or the average of per class accuracy. I've asked what @giklo is looking for

Comment: Balanced accuracy is not equivalent to per class averaged accuracy... I don't know where you are getting this from? What sklearn states is correct, but what you add is not. Balanced accuracy is used as a metric when classes are unbalanced, in which case regular accuracy might not be the most insightful measure.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing Ethan. I've added a concrete code demonstration showing that averaged per-class accuracy == balanced accuracy == recall_macro. Maybe we were talking about different things?

Comment: I've updated the code implementation above showing that per-class accuracy is equivalent to per-class recall.

Comment: A lot of things you say and do in your code are just not correct. First of all, what you present is not a multi class problem, if you only have 2 classes, it's just a binary classification.

Now the reason why in your case accuracy and recall are the same, is obvious when you look at both their formulas. Formula for accuracy: (TP+TN)/(P+N). You try to calculate the micro recall but provide just one dataset, so it will take all positive examples as one and all negative as one. This will average to this: (TP+TN)/(P+N) which is accuracy.

Comment: But you cannot prove that they are equal by forcing them to be equal here.

You give only one dataset and then use micro recall (should just be binary here) and then you also provide two 'classes' which you just use as two binary classifiers. 

The formulas for these metrics are simple enough to prove that they are not equal, but forcing them to be by making these mistakes and calling it empirical evidence is no way of proving something.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ramit.singh.pahwa/micro-macro-precision-recall-and-f-score-44439de1a044

Look here for the formula of micro recall